# Error establishing a database connection Recurring

Tags: mysql, server, digital-ocean

My server keep reporting this error.

I think there is something wrong with the mySQL server.

Every time I go into it and restart it and log in with:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

My site works again temporarily but then reverts back to

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

Comment: Which part of your tech stack cannot connect to MySQL?  Simply because you establish a session using `mysqld_safe` from the command prompt does not mean that, for example, a web application will be able to connect.

Comment: Check mysql logs and see if there's any correlation between the time the error occurs and entries in the log file. Most likely the logs will be under /var/log/mysql or [check out this question](http://superuser.com/questions/660768/where-are-logs-of-mysql-fedora) to find where your logs reside.

Comment: So I see a lot of lines that say "found invalid password for user" and it a bunch of user names I do not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that your server is running out of memory, I would suggest creating a Swapfile. You can read how to do this in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04